# Flatten list from recursive function in Python

Tags: python, list, recursion, dictionary

I'm trying to find a way to flatten my list so it outputs:

```
['one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five', 'six', 'seven', 'eight', 'nine']
```

So far my recursive function returns a new nested list of values with matched keys in a dictionary (using an old parameter list and a dictionary) is as follows:

```
l = ['won', 'too', 'three', 'fore', 'five', 'six', 'seven', 'ate', 'nein']
d = dict(won='one', too='two', fore='four', ate='eight', nein='nine')

def subst(l,d):
     if len(l) == 1:
         if l[0] in d:
             return d[l[0]]
         else:
             return l[0]
     else:
         return [d[l[0]] if l[0] in d else l[0]] + [subst(l[1:],d)]
```

So far I've been getting:

```
['one', ['two', ['three', ['four', ['five', ['six', ['seven', ['eight', 'nine']]]]]]]]
```

Is there any way I can flatten the list while keeping the recursive integrity of the function?

Answer (score 1):

You could omit the `[]` around the recursive `subst()` call.

Alternatively, you could do

```
def subst(l, d):
    return [d.get(i, i) for i in l]
```

which just iterates over the list and replaces each item with the respective entry in `d`, if any, creating a new list with the results.

If you'd rather keep the list, you could do

```
def subst(l, d):
    for n, i in enumerate(l):
        l[n] = d.get(i, i)
```

---

In a meanwhile deleted answer, [someone asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21723417/21723524?noredirect=1#comment32850778_21723544) about the race condition in `[d[x] for x in l if x in d]`.

The race condition - in the case of a threaded program - consists of the separation between `if x in d` and the `d[x]` access. If another thread deletes exactly that entry in the dict referenced by `d`, the test succeeds, but the access nevertheless fails.

Comment: If I omit the `[]` around the recursive `subst()` call, I would get a `TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "str") to list`.

Comment: @user2559679: because your code doesn't always return a list... fix it

Comment: @Karoly Horvath Eureka! Thank you! The break/base case in the function returns a string. Just fixed it with some `[]`.

Answer (score 1):

```
map(lambda x: d[x] if x in d else x,l)
```

Comment: Perhaps you could add some description to your answer? Just posting a piece of code without explanation is rarely helpful.